# How can I pull a URL stored inside a Mapbox dataset and add it to a 'click' function on a popup?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a function code that pulls data from the "description" field and displays it inside a popup on mouseenter, but can someone help me figure out how to pull in the URL stored inside "linkurl" and use it to open that URL when the icon is clicked?  The popup displays properly over an icon, but I can't figure out how to bring the URL in as a link on click.  Here's the code I'm working with:

```
map.on('load', function() {

  // Create a popup, but don't add it to the map yet.
  var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
    closeButton: false,
    closeOnClick: false
  });



// POINTS OF INTEREST
  function showPopup(e) {
    // Updates the cursor to a hand (interactivity)
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';

    // Show the popup at the coordinates with some data
    popup
      .setLngLat(e.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
      .setHTML(checkEmpty(e.features[0].properties.description))
      .addTo(map);
  }

  function hidePopup() {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
    popup.remove();
  }

  function checkEmpty(info) {
    return (info) ? info : "No data";
  }

  // CHANGE: Add layer names that need to be interactive
  map.on('mouseenter', 'points-of-interest-2019', showPopup);
  map.on('mouseleave', 'points-of-interest-2019', hidePopup);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a link within the [`Popup`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#popup) itself, you can use [`Popup#setHTML`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#popup#sethtml) in conjunction with the `<a>` tag define a hyperlink. For example:

```
// Show the popup at the coordinates with some data
var properties = e.features[0].properties;
popup
  .setLngLat(e.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
  .setHTML(
    '<a href=\'' + properties.linkurl + '\'>'
    + checkEmpty(properties.description)
    + '</a>')
  .addTo(map);
```

Since creating a `Popup` with the GL JS API automatically creates a DOM element as outlined in the source code [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/ec726ef6e4fc0b4ecfd1cbbd5a1f8e6835b89d9c/src/ui/popup.js#L485-L497), there is currently not a way to make the entire `Popup` clickable to navigate to a particular link. You could instead use `Popup#setHTML` along with some minimal CSS to create a link which wraps the entire content added to the `Popup`, so that clicking the content of the `Popup` will open the link.

Alternatively, if you are using [`Marker`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker) instances and would like clicking on the marker itself to open a link, you could utilize the `options.element` parameter to specify a DOM element wrapped in a link to use as a marker. For example, consider a slight modification to [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/):

```
var el = document.createElement('a');
el.href = 'https://www.mapbox.com/'
el.className = 'marker';
el.style.backgroundImage =
  'url(https://placekitten.com/g/' +
  marker.properties.iconSize.join('/') +
  '/)';
el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

// add marker to map
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
  .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
  .addTo(map);
```

Comment: I like the approach to the first method you showed here - thank you.  However, I'm not seeing a way to position this link so that it is clickable (as soon as the mouse moves away from the block, it is hidden).

Comment: Given that you're using the mouseenter event listener (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:mouseenter), it sounds like you are using a symbol layer rather than the Marker class to display markers on your map which popups are then added to -- is that correct? If so, you can consider using the click event (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:click) in conjunction with querySourceFeatures (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#querysourcefeatures) to add/remove a popup for a symbol when clicked.

Comment: Since symbols rendered in layers are not DOM elements, the mouseenter and mouseleave events behave exactly as their names imply. This is a bit different than how hover events work for DOM elements (such as instances of the Marker class). In other words, when working with symbol layers directly and following the model in this example (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-hover/), the popup will be removed as soon as the mouse leaves the symbol to navigate into the content of the popup itself.